# Netstate and process that are not there?

Tags: port, netstat, pid, glassfish

8080 port is occupied so I can not start glass fish server  on it , so I use netstate and find the PID of program whom use that port , but problem start here there is no process or service with this PID in task manager . what should I do?

```
netstat -aon | find ":8080" | find "LISTENING"

TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2056
```

there is no process with this pid .

**answer :**

I just find it and put the answer here for whom ever have the same problem .
I use ProcessExplorer of Microsoft and in that program it showed that rundll32 is the  program who keep port occupid , I kill the parent of rundll32 ,(in ProcessExplorer it will show you who called what program) there was somE srvhost that was calling rundll32 so I kill them and everything is COOL.